# Nodejs Firestore: Returning nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firebase to check a users punishment history, and when I call it:
I want it to return the array of embeds to post rather than just that. I am awaiting the function so I'm kind of confused why this is happening

- This is what happens in the console.log:

  [image]

  ```
  [AsyncFunction: CheckHistory]
  ```
- CALL

  ```js
  let hist = await CheckHistory(id);
  console.log(CheckHistory);
  ```
- FUNCTION

  ```js
      async function CheckHistory(user){
        CheckBan(user);
        let historyArray = [];

        const colRef = db.collection('punishments')
        colRef.where('user', '==', user).get().then(async querySnapshot => {
          length = querySnapshot.size;
          if (querySnapshot.empty){
            console.log(querySnapshot.size)
            return 0;
          } else {
            let docs = querySnapshot.docs;
            for (let documentSnapshot of docs) {
              const revoke = documentSnapshot.get('revoke')

              let active = documentSnapshot.get('active')
              if (active = true){
                active = "Active"
              } else {
                active = `Revoked for ${revoke}`
              }
              const mod = documentSnapshot.get('mod')
              const reason = documentSnapshot.get('reason');
              const time = documentSnapshot.get('time');

              let type = documentSnapshot.get('type');
              if (type == 1){
                type = "Blacklist";
              } else if (type == 2){
                type = "Dayban";
              } else if (type == 3){
                type = "Warning";
              }

              const username = await API.getUsernameFromId(user);
              const modname = await API.getUsernameFromId(mod);

              const historyEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('#0099ff')
                .setTitle(`'Punishment of ${username}:${user}`)
                .setDescription(`This is a punishment log.`)
                .addFields(
                  { name: 'Status', value: `${active}`},
                  { name: 'Moderator', value: `${modname}:${mod}` },
                  { name: 'Reason', value: `${reason}` },
                  { name: 'Type', value: `${type}` },
                  { name: 'Time', value: `<t:${time}>`}
                )

              historyArray.push(historyEmbed);

              if (historyArray.length >= length) {
                return historyArray;
              }
            }
          }
        });
      }
  ```

Comment: You forgot to actually return anything from your method, you should `return colRef.where('user', '==', user).get().then....`. Or to change .then() callback approach to actually `await` one. Like `const querySnapshot = await colRef.where('user', '==', user).get();` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by [@Sergey Sosunov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5767872/sergey-sosunov):

> You forgot to actually return anything from your method, you should
>
> ```js
> return colRef.where('user', '==', user).get().then....
> ```
>
> Or to change `.then()` callback approach to actually `await` one.
> Like:
>
> ```js
> const querySnapshot = await colRef.where('user', '==', user).get();
> ```
>
> and so on.

---

Also, the way you call the function only returns function definition; you should pass with parameters or print the variable value equal to your function. For example:

```js
//Sample function
function test(id) { return id; }

//Returns function definition
console.log(test) 

//Returns function value
console.log(test(1))

//Print variable value
let x = test(1)
console.log(x)
```